# how to compile aws-sdk-cpp kinesis?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis, aws-sdk-cpp

Trying to build a simple kinesis client app using aws-sdk-cpp

The problem is that no one seems (not even the AWS website *nudge*) to have simple examples on kinesis with simple barebones example CMakeLists.txt for kinesis. On top of that, its either that the CMakeList.txt is up to date but is too blown out of proportion OR the CMakeLists.txt is not up to date and I end up getting errors.

Could someone provide a simple barebones CMakeList.txt example for the Threadpool example on the AWS website:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/category/cpp/?nc1=f_ls

OS: OSX Sierra 10.12.3
cmake version 3.9.4

NOTE: source code structure would be organized as ./source ./model ./build, etc.

Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated. Thx

Comment: Are you building for Linux or Windows?

Comment: OSX Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: Sorry, I do all my AWS C++ SDK work on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

So after carefully going and siftig through different documentation I was able to piece together a working CMakeList.txt file. Disregard question